# How to read a description text from an item coming from a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, textview

I want to create a ListView in an Activity with a few items (say Item1 item2 item3..) and when I click on (say item1) it proceeds to the next Activity to give me a TextView (description text) and the same repeats for item2 and item3. How can I do that?

Comment: can u update your listitem layout that u inflate in getview

Comment: use this tutorial to implement listview http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add Listview `setOnItemClickListener` and get Description of text.

```
list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2,
        long arg3) {
          String description=alist.get(arg2);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
    list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2,
        long arg3) {
           TextView text = (TextView) view.findviewbyid(text view reference);
          String description=text .gettext();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,int position, long arg3) 
    {
          String description = datalist.get(position);// datalist is the list of data which is use to create listview
          Intent intent = new Intent(FirstAcitivity.this, Activity2.class);
          intent.putExtra("description", description);// sending value to next activity

    }
});
```

And in Your Activity2(destination activity after clicking/tapping user move )

```
String description = getIntent().getExtras().getString("description");// get description/value from activity which called this (Activity1)
```

Comment: Sir,can i get your email address so that i can send you my codes because i am unable to attach these codes here?? actually am almost done till the expandable listview with its subitems(item1 item2...) but what am unable to do is that i don't know where to place your given codes in my project so as to get the description of (say item1).Please do check my codes:)Thank you :)

Comment: let me know  what is your exact problem? which line of code you did not understand, where you have to put?.

Comment: Well first of all these are present in my project:FirstAcitivity.java,Activity_main.xml,parent_layout.xml,child_layout.xml, MyAdapter.java. :) Now my problem is that i don't know WHERE TO PLACE your given codes in my project...Also please tell me whether i should CREATE another activity like in your codes(say Activity2.class and Activity1) to place your given codes because when i copy and pasted this i got errors. Thank you :)

Comment: mahesh@fusionitechnologies.com

Comment: I have updated my code as your requirement. Now Activity2 is your Next activity as you mention in your question  "next Activity to give me a TextView "

Comment: E-mail sent to you check.

Comment: Ok Sir..i re fowarded u my email.